# BASH - convert array string to array

Tags: bash, shell

I am getting following string and I am trying to convert that into array.

`[ "aaa", "bbb" ]`

Would someone let me know if there is a way to convert this into BASH array.

Comment: Is this a JSON array containing JSON strings?

Comment: yes, I think so, I am getting above as part of output.

Comment: If it is possible to programmatically define a parser for the string, then you can convert it into a bash array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jq` to extract the individual strings, and then read them line by line:

```
myJsonArray='[ "aaa", "bbb", "more \"complex\"\u0020value" ]'
mapfile -t myBashArray < <(jq -r '.[]' <<< "$myJsonArray")
declare -p myBashArray
```

This outputs `declare -a myBashArray=([0]="aaa" [1]="bbb" [2]="more \"complex\" value")`

If you additionally want to support elements with linefeeds and such, you can have `jq` output NUL-separated values with a bit more work:

```
myJsonArray='[ "multi\nline\ndata", "hostile'\''\"\u0000\n$(rm foo)data" ]'
array=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' line
do
  array+=("$line")
done < <(jq -j '(.[] | gsub("\u0000"; "")) + "\u0000"' <<< "$myJsonArray")

declare -p array
```

This outputs `declare -a array=([0]=$'multi\nline\ndata' [1]=$'hostile\'"\n$(rm foo)data')`

It makes sure NUL bytes in the data don't interfere, but they will be stripped from the output. This is unlikely to matter since Bash variables can't represent NUL bytes in the first place.